# How can I determine if Windows 10 is Home regardless of PCs language settings

Tags: windows-10, version, wmi

Finding the version of Windows 10 via registry is easy enough, but determining if Home, Pro or Enterprise not-so-much if looking for those words NOT in English.

In Win32_OperatingSystem\Caption I can see e.g. "Microsoft Windows 10 Pro"

Is there some key to check via a non-language specific way because "Home" is not the case in, say, French where is Famille and Pro is Professionnel.

Adding each possible language variation to code is beyond ugly.

Comment: Are you asking how to do that in a code or you just want to know about your pc? Please be more clear

Comment: It is risky, especially so for Win10 where Microsoft wanted to get rid of this kind of identification because there are so many SKUs.  Forced upon them by local government regulations and a desire to move into embedded and mobile markets.  So you have to be specific about what you want to detect.  You can unambiguously get "Home" from the SuiteMask property.

Comment: I'm looking for use in code, not just about my PC.

Comment: @Hans - SuiteMask property using WMI returns 272 on my Windows 10 Pro, and Windows Dev Center indicates 512 = Home.  But the same article does not even show a SuiteMask for Pro.  

From [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem)

I'm good if 512=Home is reliable as that's all I care about for this use case.  Just can't test as I have no Home editions to test against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the use case I have there is a simple if/then to follow since I ONLY care about Home editions of Windows 10:

You can parse the result of a WMI query of Win32_OperatingSystem\Caption. As far as I could determine, other than France, look for "Home". France got "Famille".  Fine, they are very, very big on frowning on non-French words for anything.  If neither of those then use the the Win32_OperatingSystem\OperatingSystemSKU. 2,3,5 and 26 are all Home edition.

@magicandre1981 suggesting the GetProductInfo API doesn't work given this is for use via WMI, nevertheless that API underpins WMI.  Nothing there that would make a difference.

All of this falls WAY short of a bullet-proof way to know what a user actually has, but it is but IMHO works to weed out Home edition users.  If anyone has a better way, please post.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GetProductInfo API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getproductinfo) and check for the following return values:

```
0x00000065 (PRODUCT_CORE - Home)
0x00000063 (PRODUCT_CORE_COUNTRYSPECIFIC - Home China)
0x00000062 (PRODUCT_CORE_N - Home N)
0x00000064 (PRODUCT_CORE_SINGLELANGUAGE - Home Single Language)
```

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned use in code as opposed to Sterconium reply.  Want to use it via a WMI query. Responded above to Hans

Comment: this is the only correct way to determine Windows 10 Home.

Comment: So you're saying that WMI can't do this?  What if I am not building an app to use the API call?  Surely there are a bazillion admins out there that use WMI or PS to get this info.  Not buying it.  Please clarify why WMI can't do it using the SuiteMask in win32-operatingsystem  class.